# Remove new line, space from file

Tags: text-processing, wc, whitespace

I have many files in a directory each like so:

```
AAA 
AA

AAAAAA
A


AAAA
```

I want to end up with this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

So that when I run:

```
find ./ -name '*' -exec wc -m {} +
```

I get back 16, not 20+ depending on how many new line/spaces are counted.

Basically, I want to remove EVERYTHING from a file unless it is a letter.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you remove every newline character from a file, even the last one, then it's no longer a text file (unless the file ends up being empty) as a text file contains a sequence of text lines, text lines being delimited by newline characters.

Now, to remove all but alphabetical characters (any alphabet), as @Kusalanada said, POSIXly, you'd use `tr -cd '[:alpha:]'`.

Now, unfortunately, with some `tr` implementations, [including GNU `tr`](/q/228558), that doesn't work for multi-byte characters. In UTF-8 locales, that means all characters but ASCII ones.

On GNU systems, you can use GNU `awk` or GNU `sed` which do support multibyte characters:

```
<file sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]//g' | tr -d '\n'

<file awk -v ORS= '{gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/, ""); print}'
```

That syntax is not GNU-specific, but you'll find some non-GNU `sed`/`awk` implementations that don't support multibyte characters. Beware that GNU `sed`/`awk` at least will not remove sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters (like the output of `printf 'à b \200\n'` in a UTF-8 locale).

With `uconv` from the ICU project, you could do:

```
<file uconv -i -x '[^[:Letter:]]>;'
```

Where `-i` tells `uconv` to skip input it can't decode.

But that only works for UTF-8 data. Note that it uses Unicode character properties (some version of Unicode)  as opposed to what your locale decides what's alphabetical or not.

With GNU `grep`, you could use:

```
<file grep -o '[:alpha:]' | tr -d '\n'
```

Or if built with PCRE support (using Unicode properties):

```
<file grep -Po '\pL' | tr -d '\n'
```

With GNU `awk`, another approach to skip the invalid input is to use `RS`:

```
<file gawk -v RS='[[:alpha:]]' -v ORS= '{print RT}'
```

To modify the files in-place, you can use `gawk`'s `inplace` module:

```
gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk gawk -v RS='[[:alpha:]]' -v ORS= '{print RT}' file
```

**Do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `-name '*'` as you want to process *every* file (`*` matches every file anyway, so it does not make any difference).  You might however want `-type f` to only process regular files (not directories etc.)

To remove anything that is not a letter, you may use

```
tr -cd '[:alpha:]' <file
```

The `-c` complements the given set of characters, and `[:alpha:]` matches only alphabetical characters.  The `-d` instructs `tr` to delete the matching characters.

The command you may want to execute is therefore

```
tr -cd '[:alpha:]' <file | wc -m
```

for each file.

Since this is too complex for `find` to execute directly, you will have to employ an in-line script:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        tr -cd "[:alpha:]" <"$pathname" | wc -m
    done' sh {} +
```

Here, the in-line `sh -c` script will get batches of pathnames of files as arguments from `find`.  The pipeline will be executed for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'S:g/ <-alpha> //.put given lines;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -e 'S:g/ <- :L > //.put given lines;'  file
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -e 'S:g/ <-alpha> //.put given slurp;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -e 'S:g/ <- :L > //.put given slurp;'  file
```

Raku features high-level support for Unicode built-in, so no external libraries need be loaded to count multibyte characters. The Regex character-class `:L` denotes Unicode letters, and the `<- :L >` means "everything but" Unicode letters will get deleted in the substitution.

Sample Input (first line w/ ~ 6 trailing spaces, sixth line with ~ 12 spaces):

```
AAA     
AA1234

ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆ
1234
       
AAAA
```

Sample Output:

```
AAAAAÀÁÂÃÄÅÆAAAA
```

Counting characters:

```
~$ raku -e 'S:g/ <- :L > //.raku.put given lines;'  file
"AAAAAÀÁÂÃÄÅÆAAAA"
~$ raku -e 'S:g/ <- :L > //.chars.put given lines;'  file
16
~$ raku -e 'S:g/ <- :L > //.comb.elems.put given lines;'  file
16
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode
https://raku.org